# guard let number as NSString and NSNumber

Tags: swift, nsstring, nsnumber

I am getting data from different sources, the variable could be a number or a string of number. How do I make sure that "(number as? NSString)" or "(number as? NSNumber)" always success? Something similar to Java **optInt**, which will never fail even if the number is a String. See example below:

```
func testNumber()
    {
        var number = 123
        guard let a = (number as? NSNumber)?.intValue else { print("1");return; }
    }

func testNumberString()
{
    var number = "123"
    guard let a = (number as? NSNumber)?.intValue else { print("2");return; } // this failed.
}
func testNumberToString()
{
        var number = 123
        guard let a = (number as? NSString)?.intValue else { print("2");return; } // this sometimes failed too depend on datasource.
}
```

Comment: So you want number/ Int at the end no matter if the input is string or int right?

Comment: Did u mean that your input is number or string but you want integer as return? if yes then you can use generic.

Comment: @RajaKishan i wish to choose the end result to be NSString or NSNumber depending on different circumstance, without error.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand from your question, you want an integer value at the end, no matter if the input type is string or integer.

You can achieve this by using `ExpressibleByStringLiteral`.

Here is the demo

```
extension Int: ExpressibleByStringLiteral {
    public typealias StringLiteralType = String
    
    public init(stringLiteral value: StringLiteralType) {
        self = Int(value) ?? 0
    }
}
```

This `Int` extension allows you to accept string value as Int and return `int` value. If it did not convert it will give you `0` by default.

Example

```
func testInt() {
    let numberOne: Int = "5656"
    let numberTwo: Int = 1234
    print(numberOne)
    print(numberTwo)
}
```

Or another way is to create your own `ExpressibleByStringLiteral`, which helps you to give default value as you want.

```
struct StringInt: ExpressibleByStringLiteral {
    var value: Int?
    init(stringLiteral value: String) {
        self.value = Int("\(value)")
    }
    
    func wrapped(with defaultValue: Int) -> Int {
        return self.value ?? defaultValue
    }
}
```

Example

```
func testInt() {
    var numberThree: StringInt = "5656"
    print(numberThree.value as Any) // with nil or optional value
    
    numberThree = "asf"
    print(numberThree.wrapped(with: 15)) // with default value
    
    /**
     Output
     Optional(5656)
     15
     */
}
```

Comment: String interpolation to create a string from a string is redundant.

Comment: @vadian I'm not getting your point. could you please add more info?

Comment: Just remove `”\(` and `)”` in the init methods to create an Int from a String. `value` is already a String.

Comment: Sorry, how did I make use of that with the guard (as provided in the example) ? As the number could nil or not exist at all.

Comment: No need guard here. you will always get int value from string or int. if it fails it will give you default value same like Java optInt,

Comment: Not working if I declare var number = "123" first.

var number = "123"; // data source
let test:Int = number /// error  cannot convert value of type 'String' to specified type 'Int'
    let test:Int = number

Comment: is there any reason to assign test value by number?? You can assign direct value to test

Comment: It is necessary as the value comes from internet source API, not local. We don't assign the value directly.